# No display when printing from shared library

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I'm having an issue right now with printing to screen from a shared library. At present I'm printing to `syslog()`, but the order of the output is not correct. So I thought of using `cout` to see if that helps but nothing is displayed. Is there a way of sending output to screen from a shared library?

Comment: Nothing in particular is needed to print to standard out in a shared library. So your code is doing something particular somewhere, or you've closed or redirected standard out somewhere. (and to eliminate the obvious, keep in mind that stdout is line buffered by default, so make sure you write a newline character to flush out the output )

Comment: What command are you using to print from within the shared library?   Opening whichever dev/tty# for write, that is currently being used by the calling executable will always output to the connected terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Presumeably `stdout` has been taken for use by the main program (or its caller) because that would normally work.

Your next attempt should be to write to `cerr` (`stderr`).

If that fails, open a file writing to `/dev/tty`. That will work for all interactive console programs (but not for cron jobs, etc.)

If that doesn't work, then your only option is to write to a log file.

Comment: Thanks but nothing works.  Tried everything you suggested.  The library is loaded with the LD_PRELOAD= xxxxx.

Comment: My next step would be to write to a file. If that doesn't work then your code isn't actually running!

Comment: I added that to my answer, for completeness

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that is marked `__attribute__((constructor))` so that it is automatically run prior the the binary `main()` -- see (see [GCC Function Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) for details --, and in it, open a handle to the desired output. For example, if you want to be able to print to the terminal in your shared library, you could use

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

static FILE *terminal = NULL;

#define printterm(format...)            \
    do { if (terminal) {                \
             fprintf(terminal, format); \
             fflush(terminal);          \
       }                                \
    } while (0)

static FILE *reopentty(const int fd, const char *const mode)
{
    const char *tty = ttyname(fd);
    if (!tty)
        return NULL;
    return fopen(tty, mode);
}

static void init(void) __attribute__((constructor));

static void init(void)
{
    const int saved_errno = errno;

    if (!terminal && isatty(STDERR_FILENO))
        terminal = reopentty(STDERR_FILENO, "wb");

    if (!terminal && isatty(STDOUT_FILENO))
        terminal = reopentty(STDOUT_FILENO, "wb");

    if (!terminal && isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
        terminal = reopentty(STDIN_FILENO, "wb");

    errno = saved_errno;
}
```

Use `printterm()` instead of `printf()` to print to the terminal. It is just a wrapper macro that verifies `terminal` is non-NULL, and calls `fflush()` after each print call, to make sure the output is flushed. (You can instead make `terminal` unbuffered, but I prefer this way so that I can buffer if I need to.)

The above checks if standard error, standard output, or standard input refer to a terminal (in that order), and if so, opens `terminal` to that terminal. (If there is no terminal attached to the process, `terminal` stays NULL.)

The `terminal` variable and the functions are all marked `static`, so that they won't pollute the binary namespace. If you *have to* have a non-static variable or function, please prefix the name with your library name, so that it is as unlikely as possible to collide with an existing name in the application: instead of `terminal`, use `yourlib_terminal`.

---

Added:

Some applications reuse low descriptors unconditionally. Opening a new file uses the lowest descriptor number available, so the file descriptor underlying the *terminal* file handle might get closed/reopened/otherwise used by the application.
Some other applications are even more careful, and close all file descriptors (or at least those open to a terminal) unconditionally.

There are two ways around those.

First, you can move the descriptor to as high a number as possible:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

static FILE *terminal = NULL;

static void init(void) __attribute__((constructor));
static void fini(void) __attribute__((destructor));

static int highfd(const int oldfd)
{
    struct rlimit  nofile;
    int            maxfd, newfd;

    if (oldfd == -1)
        return -1;

    maxfd = (int)sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX) - 1;

    if (!getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &nofile))
        if (maxfd < 0L || nofile.rlim_cur > (rlim_t)maxfd)
            maxfd = nofile.rlim_cur - 1;

    while (1) {

        while (1) {

            if (maxfd < 0 || maxfd <= oldfd ||
                maxfd == STDIN_FILENO ||
                maxfd == STDOUT_FILENO ||
                maxfd == STDERR_FILENO)
                return oldfd;

            if (fcntl(maxfd, F_GETFL) == -1 && errno == EBADF)
                break;

            maxfd--;
        }

        newfd = fcntl(oldfd, F_DUPFD, (long)maxfd);
        if (newfd != -1)
            break;

        maxfd--;
    }

    close(oldfd);
    errno = 0;
    return newfd;
}

static FILE *open_tty(const int descriptor)
{
    if (isatty(descriptor)) {
        const char *const tty = ttyname(descriptor);
        if (tty) {
            const int fd = highfd(open(tty, O_WRONLY | O_NOCTTY));
            if (fd != -1) {
                return fdopen(fd, "wb");
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void init(void)
{
    if (!terminal)
        terminal = open_tty(STDERR_FILENO);
    if (!terminal)
        terminal = open_tty(STDOUT_FILENO);
    if (!terminal)
        terminal = open_tty(STDIN_FILENO);

    if (terminal) {
        fprintf(terminal, "libprinting.so: Terminal acquired.\n");
        fflush(terminal);
    }
}

void fini(void)
{
    if (terminal) {
        fprintf(terminal, "libprinting.so: Still have terminal.\n");
        fflush(terminal);
    }
}
```

Second, and even more robust but slower option, is to only open the handle to the original terminal when trying to print to it:

```
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static char *terminal_device = NULL;

static void init(void) __attribute__((constructor));
static void fini(void) __attribute__((destructor));

static void terminal_printf(const char *const fmt, ...)
{
    char   *str = NULL;
    va_list args;
    int     len, fd;

    if (!terminal_device)
        return;

    do {
        fd = open(terminal_device, O_WRONLY | O_NOCTTY);
    } while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (fd == -1)
        return;

    va_start(args, fmt);
    len = vasprintf(&str, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (len == -1)
        return;

    {
        const char       *p = str;
        const char *const q = str + len;
        ssize_t           n;

        while (p < q) {
            n = write(fd, p, (size_t)(q - p));
            if (n > (ssize_t)0)
                p += n;
            else
            if (n != (ssize_t)-1 || errno != EINTR)
                break;
        }
    }

    free(str);
    close(fd);
}

void init(void)
{
    if (!terminal_device && isatty(STDERR_FILENO)) {
        const char *const tty = ttyname(STDERR_FILENO);
        if (tty && *tty)
            terminal_device = strdup(tty);
    }

    if (!terminal_device && isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)) {
        const char *const tty = ttyname(STDOUT_FILENO);
        if (tty && *tty)
            terminal_device = strdup(tty);
    }

    if (!terminal_device && isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
        const char *const tty = ttyname(STDIN_FILENO);
        if (tty && *tty)
            terminal_device = strdup(tty);
    }

    terminal_printf("libprinting.so: Terminal acquired.\n");
}

void fini(void)
{
    terminal_printf("libprinting.so: Still have terminal.\n");
}
```

(You don't necessarily need to use low-level I/O and GNU `vasprintf()`, you could just as well use `fdopen()` to open the descriptor, write to it normally, and then `fclose()` it. The `fclose()` does close the underlying descriptor also. I just prefer this approach.)

If the actual binary is started with standard input, output and error all redirected to files or /dev/null, then the above will not be able to find what the terminal really is.

While it is possible in most cases to use `getppid()` and `/proc/PID/fd/` to find the terminal used by the parent process, or even trace ancestor processes using `/proc/PID/status` and their terminals via `/proc/PID/fd/`, if run as the same user as the current application, I would not do that. There is always a reason why the standard streams are redirected to a file.

What I would suggest, is use the latest approach above, but add

```
if (!terminal_device) {
    const char *const dev = getenv("YOURLIB_LOGFILE");
    if (dev && *dev)
        terminal_device = strdup(dev);
}
```

to the beginning of `init()`. This means that if the user wants the shared library output to a specific log file or terminal device, they only need to set up the `YOURLIB_LOGFILE` environment variable. For the current terminal, they can do

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/libyour.so YOURLIB_LOGFILE=$(tty) command...
```

where `tty` is a Coreutils command (included in basically all Linux distributions) that outputs the path to the current terminal. Even if `command...` ends up being completely daemonized (and detached from the terminal), your shared library will still be able to output to the terminal. (The `O_NOCTTY` open flag tells the kernel to not make the terminal a controlling terminal, so using the last approach above, printing to the terminal does not un-daemonize the process.)

Questions?

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately it didn't work.  STDERR_FILENO was successful but nothing appeared on the display.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: I see a little logic error in your first example.  Specifically, stdin is being opened as "wb" which will not work as stdin is an input stream, not a output stream.

Comment: @user3629249: Incorrect. If you had tried the code, you'd know that. The code tests whether stdin refers to a terminal device (tty). Terminal device descriptors in Linux are bidirectional. All shells open the terminal device just once, in `O_RDWR` mode, and duplicate it to standard streams. If you deliberately open standard input `O_RDONLY` to the controlling terminal, you cannot expect [termios](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) or [tty_ioctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html)s to work reliably either; doing that will break a lot of other stuff too.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I tried the new version with the highfd() function.  Reloaded the library and expected message from init() but nothing appeared.  At this point I have to give up.  Thanks for your input, maybe the code will work in some other scenario.

Comment: @Smithy: I think it is likely, then, that the application does close all descriptors. The second added approach (the one containing `terminal_device`) should work even then.